# If $Y\to Z$ is a monomorphism then $X_1\times_Y X_2 \to X_1\times_Z X_2$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

This is an (easy) exercise from Vakil's textbook on Algebraic Geometry. We are working in an arbitrary category, let $Y\to Z$ be a monomorphism and we are given maps $X_1, X_2\to Y, X_1, X_2\to Z$. We can also assume that $Y\times_ZY$ exists and that the induced map $Y\to Y\times_Z Y$ is an isomorphism. We need to show that the induced map $X_1\times_Y X_2 \to X_1\times_Z X_2$ is an isomorphism.

I am trying to do this using the 'magic diagram', so I get the following diagram

[image]

The top square is the magic diagram and so it is Cartesian. The map $f$ comes from the fact that the square is Cartesian and we have maps $k$ and the equality. Now, I am trying to use the fact that if $\phi$ is a monomorphism then there is at most one map $P\to Y$ making the diagram

[image]

commute. Denote the isomorphism $Y\to Y\times_Z Y$ by $m$. It is clear that $m\circ k=h$ so that we do get an $f$ indeed. This implies that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_{X_1\times_Z X_2}$. I am not sure that this is correct. Now I also need to show that $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_{X_1\times_Y X_2}$. I am interested in a proof which uses the magic diagram, as I am aware of a proof which does not.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the fact that $φ$ is monomorphism any more - you already did that by assuming $Y → Y ×_Z Y$ is isomorphism, which is equivalent to $φ$ being mono. All that is left to do is to observe that the bottom square is also cartesian (for trivial reasons), which makes the whole outer square cartesian too. Now $g$, being a pullback of an isomorphism ($\mathrm{id}_Z$), has to be an isomorphism.

You don't even have to construct the inverse, although your attempt does work. The way to check that $fg = \mathrm{id}$ would be to precompose your entire diagram with $g$ and then check that $fg$ and $\mathrm{id}$ are the same when composed with both $g$ and $φj$.